# Creating a cat like program

Tags: c, file-io, operating-system, posix

I am trying a write a program that implements a bare bones POSIX `cat` command. Although I have written the code and it behaves normally for the default (without paramaters) `STDIN`, It doesn't work well for others. Can anyone help me with this. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 10240
#define MAX_FILES 127

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n,t,i;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    char *myargv[MAX_FILES];
    //aiparser(argv,myargv);
    if (argc == 1) {
        while(( n = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf ,n ) != n) {
                perror("Write Error");
            }
        }
        if ( n < 0 ) {
            perror("Read Error");
        }
    }
    else {
        for ( i = 1; i < argc-1 ; i++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i],"-") != 0 ) {
                t = open(argv[i],O_RDONLY);
            }
            else {
                t = STDIN_FILENO;
            }
            while(( n = read(t,buf,BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
                if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf ,n ) != n) {
                    perror("Write Error");
                }
            }
            if ( n < 0 ) {
                perror("Read Error");
            }
            if (close(t) == -1) {
                perror("Closing Error");
            }
        }
        }   
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please explain _exactly how_ it behaves in the "others" case.

Comment: Is "it doesn't work well" the height of your level of technical detail?

Comment: Forgive me for my naive details but while running the program it simply exists. I think the for loop under the else part is never executed.

Comment: You "think"? You mean, you really have no idea how you could obtain some diagnostic data that *tells* you whether that branch of the code is being executed? Sorry for sounding harsh, but if you want to program anything more serious, you'll probably encounter many, many similar obstacles in the future!

Comment: Through some `printf(3)` statements in there to find out for sure what's happening -- many people like debuggers to find this out, but I find `printf(3)` is a superb debugging aid.

Comment: +1 for the complete example though. Note that you were missing the `<strng.h>` header for `strcmp(3)`.

Comment: @sarnold Thanks, your suggestion helped me figure out the bug. It was the i < argc -1 which should have been i <= argc -1 .

Comment: Cool, a nice SO success story: Not only Warangalite found the problem on its own, but also learned a helpful technique to overcome similar obstacles in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

i < argc-1

...which would mean you'd *never* actually execute the loop at all if you only pass a single argument.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out myself too. Still thanks for taking time to read through my code.

Comment: You are quite welcome. I should also point out you *would* do the loop if you passed more than one filename - meaning if you passed two filenames, you'd get one; three filenames, you'd get two, etc.; but passing a single argument would yield.... nothing.

Comment: You should probably also ignore cases where read & write return -1 and errno is EAGAIN or EINTR. Just continue looping. I don't think you'll hit EAGAIN because the file won't be set to non-blocking in this case, but the check won't hurt.